# Extending an F-Curve in a certain channel

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I am animating this long walk for a character. And it is super easy to duplicate the keyframes of the walk cycle. But I'm facing the challenge of keeping the Torso (The Root) consistently going forward on the Y axis. I am not a big fan of NLA. And I also want to add some nuances to the walk throughout the animation, so for me the Action Editor is a no go.

In the Below Image on the Graph Editor, I managed to manually duplicate the Y keyframes from 1 to 41. At frame 41, the walk cycle ends and I have to repeat it a couple of more times. But unlike the rest of the walk cycle keyframes, the Torso's are not stationary and they have to dynamically translate along the Y channel. Is there a way I can extend "prolong" this curve consistently across in the Y Location Channel?

I also attached the Blend file for your reference.

https://www.mediafire.com/file/tsdmfmr9h1ii44i/Blender+Exchange+File.blend/file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you select a point of the F curve you can read its values on the view tab on the right of the curves window (just under modifiers).

I'm assuming that your first keyframe you want to copy is frame 3, value 0.7, and the last is frame 65, value - 2.3.

So you want to copy the curve with an offset of 63 frames on X and a value of 3 on Y.

So select the curve points, shift D to duplicate, X to move on X axis, 63, Enter.

Then Press G, Y, - 3 Enter.

Then you'll have to globally adjust the Y values of the copied keyframes to compensate the needed little movement between frame 65 and 66.